# Meteor insert doesnt work

Tags: javascript, meteor

normally my inserts are working fine but today i could crush Meteor ;)

I already removed insecure and Autopublish and checked the code hundred times but the insert gets not executed.

My hmtl:

```
<template name="neuesGebietErstellen">
    <div id="viewport">
        <form class="add-Gebiet">
            <input type="text" name="Gebietsname" placeholder="Gebietsname"><br>
            <input type="text" name="Gebietsnummer" placeholder="Gebietsnummer"><br>
            <input type="text" name="Ort" placeholder="Stadt / Ort"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Gebiet hinzufügen">
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

my js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'

Template.neuesGebietErstellen.onCreated(function () {
    this.subscribe('gebiete');
});


Template.neuesGebietErstellen.events({
    "submit .add-Gebiet": function (event) {
        var Gebietsname = event.target.Gebietsname.value;
        var Gebietsnummer = event.target.Gebietsnummer.value;
        var Ort = event.target.Ort.value;

        Meteor.call('neuesGebiet', Gebietsname, Gebietsnummer, Ort)

        console.log("hat geklappt");
        return false; 
 }
});
```

My method file in the server folder:

```
Meteor.methods({
    neuesGebiet(Gebietsname, Gebietsnummer, Ort) {
        console.log("Methode wurde aufgerufen");

         Gebiete.insert({            
            Gebietsname: Gebietsname,
            Gebietsnummer: Gebietsnummer,
            Ort: Ort
        });        
    }
});
```

The strange part is i get both console logs so my event is executed and the method is called too but with meteor toys i check my collection and there nothing is getting inserted. So please help me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the problem is that the record is being inserted but is not being published back out to the client so the client never sees it.

1. Have you removed the `autopublish` package? If so...
2. Are you publishing your `Gebiete` collection from the server and
3. Are you subscribing to it on the client?

Comment: you were right i had the false collection name in my publish code Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the collection-object **Gebiete** declared/defined as well like this.

```
let Gebiete = new Meteor.Collection('gebiete');
```

Comment: yes i have done that but without "let" i try it thanks ;)

Comment: try to make an dummy insert directly after `Gebiete = new Meteor.Collection('gebiete');` use therefore some static data and show if this document was saved successfully.